# Update scroll-length in Apache Cordova automatically

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, scroll, capture

Hello my dear friends and sorry for the bad english!

I programmed an app with apache cordova in that pictures can be taken. The pictures will be directly displayed on the same page. The Problem is: when I have more than two pictures, the scroll length of the site gets not updated. When I spin my phone, the scroll-length gets updated and i can scroll to the pictures further down. How can I do this automatically?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: dnt you append newly taken picture

Comment: What do you want to say? Sorry but i cant understand this.
If you mean
"dont you append a newly taken picture"
Yes, i append a newly taken picture